# Problem with file size using fread (to load) and write.csv. From 20GB to > 60GB in writing phase

Tags: r, csv, fread, filesize, tweets

My problem is that `write.csv` - or something else in my work process - has increment my file size from 19GB to more than 60GB. I mean more than 60GB because the saving process was interrupted because of memory problems. It had occurred when I added 250 000 rows to my DataBAse of near to 3 millions of rows. Now, I have 2 problems: 1) How to overcome the issue above and 2) how to read this huge Data and how to save it in a coherent size. For those who are not familiar with storing tweets, my file size is heavier than should be. I have been storing only 29 columns of 91 (standard columns when downloading tweets).

Here is my process:

I'm downloading tweets using `rtweet` thesee days. So that, I download tweets in chunks of 250 000 by day. For each day, using `fread` from `data.table`, I load my old Data Base. Then, I bind both data frames with `rbind`. Finally, I use `write.csv` to save my object. I repeat this process each time. Here my code:

```
base <- fread("tweets.csv")
base$user_id <- as.character(base$user_id)
base$status_id <- as.character(base$status_id)
base$retweet_status_id <- as.character(base$retweet_status_id)
base$retweet_user_id <- as.character(base$mentions_user_id)

datos <- search_tweets2("keywords", n = 250000, include_rts = T, lang = "es", retryonratelimit = T)

datos <- datos[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,12,14,30,31,32,48,49,50,51,54,55,56,57,61,62,73,74,75,78,79,83,84)]

datos$mentions_user_id <- as.character(datos$mentions_user_id)
datos$mentions_screen_name <- as.character(datos$mentions_screen_name)
datos$created_at <- as.character(datos$created_at)
datos$retweet_created_at <- as.character(datos$retweet_created_at)
datos$account_created_at <- as.character(datos$account_created_at)

base <- rbind(base,datos)
write.csv(base, "tweets.csv")
```

Need to say than when I write the new file, I overwrite. Probably, here is the main problem when loading and overwritten. I don't know. Otherwise, I've been reading and think that my solution may be in `read.csv.sql`, loading by small parts my DataBase and saving in a correct way. But `read.csv.sql` presents some problems with my number of columns. It says: "Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip) : 
  RS_sqlite_import: tweets.csv line 2 expected 29 columns of data but found 6".

I load 100 rows using 'read.csv(file.csv, nrows = 100)` to know if everything is still OK in my file and it is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using `fread`, why not use `fwrite`?

Comment: @IanCampbell  I proved that, but `fwrite` is slower than `write.csv`in my case. Don't know why.

Comment: Fascinating, have you looked into `vroom` at all, with `vroom::vroom_write`?

Comment: vroom flies!! But unfortunately, these days I have only my laptop with limit memory. Can't load all those 60GB. I think I need to load it in pieces. Then, I'll try with vroom.